# Returning an array in cocoa, but waiting for delegation to complete

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have created the following method in cocoa:

```
-(NSArray *)latestData
{
    NSURL *requestingURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"someRestfulURL"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest =[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:requestingURL];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if(theConnection)
    {
        webData = [[NSMutableData data]retain];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"the connection is NULL");
    }
    return someArray;
}
```

The RESTful webservice I am calling returns XML that I parse using NSXMLParser.

How can I return an array when calling  `latestData` if I have to wait for the delegate methods of NSURLConnection and NSXMLParser to finish before I can fill the array with the appropriate data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things you can do
1. Make the request synchronous, this way you will have the array at the time of return.
2. If you want to make it asynchronous, instead of returning the array, have the array as a class member and fill it in the finishedRequest delegate method.

Comment: I understand that making a synchronous request call will return NSData, but how could I pass this data to my parser and still return an array within the method??

Comment: Assuming your response is XML or Json , you can do [[NSString alloc] initWithData: encoding:] in order to g et your text back, then you can parse that

Comment: If you are doing a simply get you can also use 
NSString *response=[NSString stringWithContentOfURL: url] 
to get your response synchronously

Answer (score 1):

[NSXMLParser parse] doesn't return until parsing is finished, so that already has the behavior you want, and NSURLConnection has sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error: for synchronous requests.

If you are running this on your main thread though, you should really consider whether you can instead make your method asynchronous instead, as blocking the UI on a network request can make for poor user experience.

Comment: How would I do it asynchronously and still return an array?? I am having a class request this method so is a class level variable, for the array in the above method, really viable??

Comment: You would take a delegate argument, and have the delegate implement a known callback method that takes an array.

Comment: How would this be done??  Is there a
code example you could
provide me??

Comment: Cocoa is full of examples of this; the NSURLConnection call in your own sample code above is one, and sheets are another.